# Is there a way to find out the count of one element in a group of array

Tags: swift

I have an array of information pertaining to a patient. I want to have the count of the number of occurrence of one element within the array.

I am new to Swift and iOS development and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` function and then count the remaining array.

```swift
array.filter({ $0 == item }).count
```

Comment: Use `lazy`. Otherwise this will be inefficent.